# RNBootSplash.hide() does not hide the splash screen on iOS

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

I'm using react-native-bootsplash (2.2.6) package to show splash screen in my React Native (0.63.2) app.

It works on Android, however, it doesn't on iOS (physical iPhone 8, iOS 14, but it doesn't work on simulators as well).

When I log the package import I truly see that both of the methods (`show` and `hide`) exist.
However, calling it makes no difference.

I call it in `componentDidMount` lifecycle, as well as `componentDidCatch`. As I thought it might be related to the components down the tree, I just rendered a View instead of my actual app, and it still does not work.

Here's my `AppDelegate.m` file and AppDelegate implementation:

```c
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>

#import <Firebase.h>

#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

#import "RNBootSplash.h"

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>



static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
    [FIRApp configure];
  }
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"MY_API_KEY"];// add this line using the api key obtained from Google Console

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"BUILDS"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  // I added the following 3 lines per react-native docs against blinking issue when Splash Screen is hiding (I used react-native-splash-screen package before.)

  UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"BootSplash" bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
  rootView.loadingView = vc.view;

  center.delegate = self;
  
  [RNBootSplash initWithStoryboard:@"BootSplash" rootView:rootView]; // <- initialization using the storyboard file name
  return YES;
}
```

[image: Here's my project directory files:]

[image: Here's the screenshot of my configuration for App Icons and Launch Images]

And this is my `index.js` (Commented out the real app, and just using an empty View with a text)

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
if (__DEV__) {
    import('./ReactotronConfig').then(() => console.log('Reactotron Configured'))
}

import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
// import App from './src/app/App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';


import RNBootSplash from 'react-native-bootsplash'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        RNBootSplash.hide()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={ { flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' } } >
                <Text> textInComponent </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you using RN >= 0.71, use must change the line in AppDelegate.mm to

```
    bool didFinish = [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  
  [RNSplashScreen show];
  
  return didFinish;
```

I found this solution at: https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/issues/606#issuecomment-1401875339

And it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it didn't work and why it works now, but commenting out the lines I mentioned in the question resolved the issue.
I just commented out the following lines:

```objectivec
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"BootSplash" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
rootView.loadingView = vc.view;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be making splash show more than once by some code within AppDelegate.m

For example, the below will keep splash showing. Best to hide / replace this with BootSplash code.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Launch Screen" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
rootView.loadingView = vc.view;
```

Update to

```
[RNBootSplash initWithStoryboard:@"BootSplash" rootView:rootView];
```

Make sure to also hide within the code, for example

```
RNBootSplash.hide({ fade: true });
```